Laravel11 SMTP and verify Mail
I'm new in the laravel world and setup a complete new laravel11 environment with composer.
I implemented the login and register option for the frontend with the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/verification
Now there is a problem: if I use "log" as MAIL_MAILER in the .env file everything is fine and I got the mail in the log. The routes also redirects correctly and if I copy the verify mail link and execute it, it also works fine.
When I switch to smtp as MAIL_MAILER there is no Mail sent.
So I tried if my SMTP config is correct in an smtp test tool (for example https://dnschecker.org/smtp-test-tool.php )
If I choose TLS and Port 587 or 25  ... the tool works
If I choose SSL and 465 the tool didnt work.
But my Mail SMTP Service says I need Port 465, but the other ways worked in the test tool.
I tried all combinations from MAIL_ENCRYPTION and MAIL_PORT in the env file, but none of it works when starting a registration in laravel.
Are there any ideas ?

Port 465 is no more used, its outdated should work with port 587 or 25 either
